# How to use content address in sed on osx without error "expected context address"

Tags: sed, osx

I'm getting this error

```
sed: 2: "
/^[[:space:]]*pause$/, ...": expected context address
```

with this line:

```
/^[[:space:]]*pause$/,+1d
```

which works on my debian Ubuntu system.

The full file is

```
file_in=$1
sed -e'
#
# Delete whole lines
/^<?xml/d
/^<[!]DOCTYPE/d
/^<\(.*html\|.*head\|meta\|.*body\)/d
/^<\(.*table\|.*head\|meta\|.*body\)/d
/^[[:space:]]*<[/]*tr.*>$/d
/storeConfirmation/d
#
# Remove pieces of a line
s/<td>//
s%</*td.*>%%
#
# Replacements - chunks
/^<link/ {
  s/<link rel="selenium.base" href/@link/
  s%[[:space:]]*/>%%
}
/^<title/ {
  s/<title>/feature "/
  s%</title>%" do%
}
/^.*>>>>> / {
  s/^.*>>>>>[[:space:]]*/scenario "/
  s/$/ do/
}
s/-->/"/
s/^.*<<<<<.*/end/
s/<[!]--/#/
/^#/ {
  s/^##/#/
  s/"$//
}
#
# Replacements - characters
/\${/ {
  s/\$/@/g
  s/{//g
  s/}//g
}
s/^[[:space:]]*//
/^[[:space:]]*$/d' $file_in |
sed -e'
/^[[:space:]]*pause$/,+1d
/deleteAllVisibleCookies/d
/click\|wait\|assert/ {
  N;
  s/\n/ /
}
/@.*@/ {
  s/@/+ @/2
}
/select\|type/ {
  N;
  N;
  s/\n/ /g
}
$ a end
'
```

Sample input

```
<tr>
        <td>waitForVisible</td>
        <td>${css_delete_violation}</td>
        <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
        <td>click</td>
        <td>${css_delete_violation}</td>
        <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
        <td>storeConfirmation</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
        <td>pause</td>
        <td>2000</td>
        <td></td>
</tr>
```

I also tried:

```
/^[[:space:]]*pause$/0,+1d
/^[[:space:]]*pause$/1,+1d
/^[[:space:]]*pause$/+1d
/^[[:space:]]*pause$/1d
/^[[:space:]]*pause$/1,2d
```

but they all give invalid command code

I also tried:

```
...
sed -E '
/^[[:space:]]*pause$/,+1d
...
```

Comment: Could you please provide a minimal input file.

Comment: Added that to the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Linux usually has GNU sed, OS X uses sed from BSD. The address '/pattern/,+1' is a GNU extension, it will not work with other sed implementations.

What might work is the following (joining a line with the next, then deleting the line):

```
/pattern$/N; /pattern/d
```

At least that worked on OS X 10.10. Notice the different patterns.

As your goal is to to manipulate an XML file, sed isn't the right tool to begin with. For example have a look at Python and it's lxml module (not part of Python's Standard lib); that combination worked well for me.